# How to compile an OpenGL project in CMake in Wayland desktop environment?

Tags: c++, c++11, opengl, cmake

I'm trying to setup a project that uses OpenGL as library for graphic development; in particular, I want to use CMake for compiling the project to make it cross-platform.
I'm running the project on Arch Linux distro with KDE as desktop environment.

This is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5.0)
project(run VERSION 0.1.0 LANGUAGES C CXX)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

add_executable(run main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(
    run PUBLIC
    /usr/lib/libglut.so.3
    /usr/lib/libOpenGL.so.0
    /usr/lib/libglfw.so.3.3
    /usr/lib/libGLEW.so.2.2
    /usr/lib/libdecor/plugins-1/libdecor-gtk.so
)
################################################
set(INCLUDE_ROOT_FOLDER "/usr/include")

target_include_directories(
    run PUBLIC
    ${INCLUDE_ROOT_FOLDER}/GL
    ${INCLUDE_ROOT_FOLDER}/GLFW
    ${INCLUDE_ROOT_FOLDER}/libdecor-0
    ${INCLUDE_ROOT_FOLDER}
)
set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)
```

and this is main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <glew.h>
#include <glut.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main()
{
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB);
    glfwInit();
    return 0;
}
```

When compiling, everything is fine. However, this is the error I get at run-time:

```
xkbcommon: ERROR: couldn't find a Compose file for locale "it_IT..UTF-8" (mapped to "it_IT..UTF-8")
libdecor-gtk-WARNING: Failed to initialize GTK
Failed to load plugin 'libdecor-gtk.so': failed to init
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem, which was solved by installing glfw-x11 and subsequently uninstalling glfw-wayland.

```
sudo pacman -S glfw-x11
```

I think this error has something to do with support for nvidea graphics cards.

Answer (score -1):

my problem solved after changing from wayland to x11, logout and change from plasma(wayland) to plasma(x11)